# automatically copy a config file from referenced dll

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, compilation

I have 2 projects in my VS2005 solution: Exe.csproj and Dll.csproj

Dll.csproj has an app.config

Exe.csproj has a project reference to Dll.csproj

If I compile Exe.csproj, than Dll.dll and Dll.pdb will be automatically copied to Exe/bin/debug, but Dll.dll.config not.

Is there any way to get Dll.dll.config in Exe/bin/debug without post build event technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the file (Dll.dll.config) and view it's properties.

Set Copy to Local to True. This will put the file in the output directory automatically.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: This will copy to Dll\bin\debug but not to Exe\bin\debug

Answer (score 2):

MSBuild to the rescue!

Stick the following targets into your project file:

```
 <Target Name="CopyConfig"
        Inputs="@(DetectedConfig)"
        Outputs="@(DetectedConfig->'$(OutDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
        AfterTargets="DetectConfigFiles">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(DetectedConfig)"
          DestinationFiles="@(DetectedConfig->'$(OutDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
        <Output TaskParameter="CopiedFiles"
                ItemName="CopiedConfig" />

    </Copy>
    <Message Importance="High"
             Condition="'%(CopiedConfig.FullPath)'!=''"
             Text="Copied config: %(CopiedConfig.FullPath)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="DetectConfigFiles" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Add .config onto all the assemblies we reference -->
        <PossibleConfig Include="%(ReferencePath.FullPath).config" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Work out which ones actually exist in the file system -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <DetectedConfig Include="@(PossibleConfig)" Condition="Exists('%(PossibleConfig.Identity)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```